# I'm creating and e-commerce store website using hygrapg graphql cms and when I'm fetching data nothing renders on the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

(new to the React framework) I am creating this e-commerce website using React. I'm using graphql as a CMS and when I'm fetching the data using `graphcms.request` nothing renders on the screen. There seems to be no errors from vscode or the console, however, when I inspect element there is a noscript tag that says "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.". I have made sure that javascript is enabled. This is my App.js. Edit: apparently this is White screen of death (WSOD).

```
import { ProductCard } from './ProductCard'

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient('secret');

const QUERY =   gql`
{
  products {
    productName
    productImage {
      url
    }
    productPrice
    slug
  }
}`

  export async function getStaticProps() {
    const {product} = await graphcms.request(QUERY);
    return{
      props:{
        product,
      },
    }
  }

function App({product}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {product?.map((product) => (
        <ProductCard Name={product.productName}/>
      ))}
      <div>Hello</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in getStaticProps it should be const {products} not const {product}. You are missing a `s`

Comment: If this issue is specific to `graphcms`, add the associated tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have replied to your support request just now :) We can continue our discussion there.

But in such cases, you should check that you are using the correct endpoint to fetch your data, and make sure that you are targeting the correct environment.
If you see in dev mode that a request is being made from the network dev tool, then please share the requestID from that request so we can look into the logs and check what is happening with that request.

Best,
Own

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).